# Css asp:menu floating

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-2010, css-float

I'm having an issue with CSS (not sure).

Actually I'm new to CSS, and I'm trying to understand it.

Ok, let's take a look:

- I've created an WebApplication (ASP.Net web) with Visual Studio 2010
- And I decided to use the original template given by VS 2010
- I've tried to make the default menu right floating. But I couldn't make that.
- The original menu looks like:

  ```
  |Home|About_______________________________|
  ```
- And I want to make it looks like:

  ```
  |_______________________________Home|About|
  ```
- I tried style="float: right;".
- I also tried dir="rtl", but I got something like:

  ```
  |_______________________________About|Home|
  ```

How can I solve this problem?

I'm not sure that it's a CSS issue or a control issue. I'm not familiar with Web Application, I've worked on Winform Application.

This is the Site.Master:

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>
                    My ASP.NET Application
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="loginDisplay">
                <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        [ <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" id="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a>
                        ]
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        Welcome <span class="bold">
                            <asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" />
                        </span>! [
                        <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out"
                            LogoutPageUrl="~/" />
                        ]
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>
            </div>
            <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false"
                    IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal" dir="rtl">
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home" />
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About" />
                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the CSS:

```
/* DEFAULTS
----------------------------------------------------------*/

body   
{
    background: #b6b7bc;
    font-size: .80em;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #696969;
}

a:link, a:visited
{
    color: #034af3;
}

a:hover
{
    color: #1d60ff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:active
{
    color: #034af3;
}

p
{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
}


/* HEADINGS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #666666;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: 200;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h1
{
    font-size: 1.6em;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h2
{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 600;
}

h3
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

h4
{
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

h5, h6
{
    font-size: 1em;
}

/* this rule styles <h1> and <h2> tags that are the 
first child of the left and right table columns */
.rightColumn > h1, .rightColumn > h2, .leftColumn > h1, .leftColumn > h2
{
    margin-top: 0px;
}


/* PRIMARY LAYOUT ELEMENTS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

.page
{
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
    border: 1px solid #496077;
}

.header
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #4b6c9e;
    width: 100%;
}

.header h1
{
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    color: #f9f9f9;
    border: none;
    line-height: 2em;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.main
{
    padding: 0px 12px;
    margin: 12px 8px 8px 8px;
    min-height: 420px;
}

.leftCol
{
    padding: 6px 0px;
    margin: 12px 8px 8px 8px;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.footer
{
    color: #4e5766;
    padding: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: normal;
}


/* TAB MENU   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

div.hideSkiplink
{
    background-color:#3a4f63;
    width:100%;
}

div.menu
{
    padding: 4px 0px 4px 8px;
}

div.menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: auto;
}

div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
{
    background-color: #465c71;
    border: 1px #4e667d solid;
    color: #dde4ec;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.35em;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.menu ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: #bfcbd6;
    color: #465c71;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.menu ul li a:active
{
    background-color: #465c71;
    color: #cfdbe6;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* FORM ELEMENTS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

fieldset
{
    margin: 1em 0px;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

fieldset p 
{
    margin: 2px 12px 10px 10px;
}

fieldset.login label, fieldset.register label, fieldset.changePassword label
{
    display: block;
}

fieldset label.inline 
{
    display: inline;
}

legend 
{
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 2px 4px 8px 4px;
}

input.textEntry 
{
    width: 320px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

input.passwordEntry 
{
    width: 320px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

div.accountInfo
{
    width: 42%;
}

/* MISC  
----------------------------------------------------------*/

.clear
{
    clear: both;
}

.title
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    width: auto;
}

.loginDisplay
{
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 10px;
    color: White;
}

.loginDisplay a:link
{
    color: white;
}

.loginDisplay a:visited
{
    color: white;
}

.loginDisplay a:hover
{
    color: white;
}

.failureNotification
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: Red;
}

.bold
{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.submitButton
{
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

All codes above are the default codes given by VS 2010.
   Help me!
Thanks alot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, I've found something, just edit the div.menu class:

```
div.menu
{
    padding: 4px 8px 4px 0px;
    float: right !important
}
```

The "!important" keyword (I'm not sure about this strange thing), make the browser render my asp:menu float style based on my css class not from the generated javascript.

I found it here: http://walaapoints.blogspot.com/2011/04/aspnet-menu-rtl.html

Comment: Are you sure about how the class created? Use "!important"  will override any other css, but it is not a very good practice, though.

Comment: I think your better way is to find how the javascript create the inline-css and stop them, to avoid conflict

Comment: Script generated by .net framework. Don't know how to stop it :)

Comment: Well, in web everything is text. There must be some way to modify it. Have you try using firebug to actually see what got rendered?

Answer (score 1):

If this is your menu

```
div.menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: auto;
}
```

then you need to add a `width` to it in order to make it float.

So something like

```
div.menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 300px;  //CHANGE THIS
    float:right;
}
```

The `width` needs to be something less than 100%/auto for it to float properly.

Comment: Oh thanks for your help, I've just tested it, and no work. Any idea?